# Kibana messed up css

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

Once I've installed a plugin to Kibana, it apparently had some CSS in it and some of the components got messed up. See the following screenshot:

[image: CSS]

Even after deleting the plugin, this styling remains. Any ideas how could I fix that?

Kibana 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the optimize/bundle directory and restart Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart kibana server

Comment: Whole host or kibana service? I've restarted Kibana service already

Comment: After restart kibana, do you have some red error in kibana server log?

Comment: I'll have to enable kibana logging to see that. Will check and come back to you